# Craft 4 doesn't support other languages yet?

Tags: language, craft4

After installing a fresh version of Craft 4, the setup didn't allow me to specify the site language fr-FR as it did with the previous version. I had to accept the default en-US.

I thought that I would be able to fix that afterward in the control panel, but the only choices available are English variants.

I don't mind if the CP isn't fully translated yet, but it seems to me that I should be able to setup multiple languages. What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the PHP docker container used by Nitro.

Craft’s team fixed it and after updating Nitro everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Found this solution that worked for me: https://github.com/craftcms/docker/issues/60

```
docker exec -it --user root YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME sh
```

then with

```
apk add icu-data-full
```

followed by a restart of the container gives me all languages back. Credit Mankeldor. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the [Intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) PHP extension, which is [required in Craft 4](https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/preparing-for-craft-4#upgrade-your-environment).

You can verify if that's the case by visiting the Utilities -> System Report section and look for the Intl status under *Requirements*:

[image]

Comment: The extension is indeed available.

Comment: Same issue. Craft 3.7.44 and Craft 4.0.4 (new install) running inside Nitro. The Intl extension is OK as well.

Comment: Update: All languages are available on staging server but not locally within Nitro. Looks like a Nitro bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running inside Nitro, try updating your docker images with `nitro update`.
It solved a similar issue for me.

Comment: I tried the `nitro update`, and checked that I could change the CP language for my user : It works. 

BUT, I am still unable to create a new site in French from the CP. The only options are local English variants.

Comment: I tried to create a brand new craft install after the `nitro update` and used the manual setup instead of the terminal to no avail, the only options are once more the English variants.